# Will slamming doors shut damage my car?

Tags: door, damage

I hate it when people slam my car doors shut, as I am convinced that they will bend and will create wind noise.

**Is it bad to slam car doors?**

**Will it cause the doors to bend?**

Comment: Slamming doors gives people heart attacks

Comment: a friend slammed the passenger front door on my 99 honda accord, resulting in a crack in the lower passenger side windshield.

Comment: At least in Germany slamming doors (especially at night) falls in the same category as driving with unnecessary high rpm, damaged exhaust, or other conditions that make loud and preventable noise. Generally there are people around you who would prefer a quieter environment than someone constantly slamming their car door :-)

Comment: My 12yr old daughter just broke my back passenger door from constant slamming, the inner mechanism broke and yes its expensive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have lived under the impression that they will not bend as the entire surface of the door that touches the body would hit evenly at the same time along the entire surface.

If you put a bar at a point on the surface near the hinge I imagine that the door would become damaged.

**damage I would worry about**

- Door internals
- Window components and arms to raise and lower windows
- Various clips popping off trim
- Locking mechanisms, especially the point of contact with the body.
- Electronic switches
- The window, I've seen windows get cracked from slamming doors and not necessarily the window that's on the door.

Comment: Not to mention the extra stress put on the door and hinges which will cause premature wear on all these parts.

Comment: It also causes a rapid increase in pressure inside the car. If you get your windshield replaced, they ask you not to close the door when all the windows are closed for the first couple days, as the spike in pressure it could break the fresh seal.

Comment: @MooseLucifer - While I've not been told this, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Ever have the door speakers come out?  Usually followed by having to readjust the window tracks and replace all the door clips and wires you broke trying to open the door panels.

Comment: There is also the classic where a door is shut to hard the glass pops off it's runners and drops to the bottom of the door, coming back out again as lots of little pieces.